# matlab's addpoints function stopped working, it says that I'm trying to use the script as a function

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm just trying to add points to an animated line like this:

```
f=figure('Visible','on','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1],'Numbertitle','off','Name','test');
for i=1:2
    S(i)=subplot(2,1,i,'Parent',f);
    h(i)=animatedline(S(i),'color','b','marker','.');
end
i=1;x=[1 2];
for j=1:numel(h)
    addpoints(h(j),i,x(j));
end
```

But I get this error:

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT addpoints as a function:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/toolbox/matlab/graphics/addpoints.m
```

Note that last time I used it it worked just fine...

BTW, I'm using matlab r2019b under ubuntu 18.04.

I went to matlab's install directory and `find . -type f -name "addpoints.m"` give me this:

```
./mcr/toolbox/matlab/graphics/addpoints.m
./toolbox/distcomp/array/+parallel/+internal/+array/@PlottableUsingGather/addpoints.m
./toolbox/matlab/graphics/addpoints.m
```

Of those 3, only the last one isn't empty and it's just a help file, no function there...

EDIT:
On matlab, `which addpoints -all` gives me:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/toolbox/matlab/graphics/addpoints.m
addpoints is a built-in method                                % matlab.graphics.animation.AnimatedLine method
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `which addpoints -all` from the command window? This will tell you the functions by that name on your path, in precedence order

Comment: added to the question :)

Comment: Add the `which` statement to the script/function that calls `addpoints`. Within the script you might have a different search path.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i got the same result from `which` from within my script

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. :(

Comment: T_T T_T T_T T_T